# Elastic Search Query for Total Count value for all the matching documents

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I am new to ElasticSearch .NET integration. I am searching my indexed data(where i have indexed more than 10000 records, But when i am searching i am getting max 250 records only even though all the 10000 records should come as all the records startswith the searched value

Please find the query written by me :

```
string UniqueID ='h';
var result = client.Search<MemberListDto>(s => s
                   .Query(q =>
                               q.MatchPhrasePrefix((mq => mq.Field(f => f.UniqueID).Query(UniqueID)))
                       ));

            return result.Total;
```

NOTE : All the UniqueID value starts with 'h' and I am giving UniqueID='h' only.

Please help me, how can i get all the 10000 records count if it is satisfying the query term value.

Here is my POCO C# class object I am trying to index :

```
public class MemberListDto
{

    [String(Analyzer = "keyword", SearchAnalyzer = "keyword")]
    public string UniqueID { get; set; }
    [String(Analyzer ="keyword",SearchAnalyzer ="keyword")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
```

}

Here is the generic code i am trying to do bulk index of list of MemberListDto object :

```
public void CreateBulkIndex<T>(List<T> data, string indexName, string typeName) where T : class
    {

        if (!_client.IndexExists(ElasticConfig.IndexName).Exists)
        {
            var indexDescriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor(ElasticConfig.IndexName)
                .Mappings(ms => ms
                    .Map<T>(m => m.AutoMap()));

            _client.CreateIndex(ElasticConfig.IndexName, i => indexDescriptor);
        }
        _client.Bulk(b => b.IndexMany(data, (d, doc) => d.Document(doc).Index(indexName)));

    }
```

Comment: just to re-check , can you please post the document which should come as per the query but is not coming?

Comment: I have indexed 10000 MemberListDto(UniqueID,...) object and All the 10000 records UniqueID value starts with 'h' followed by some integers. So when i am trying to search 'h', Total count is always 250. I tried to indexed more than 10000 records also, In that case also, It is giving 250 total only.

Comment: Can you show a more complete example? There's not enough information in your question to discern the problem. For example - what does the POCO look like, how are you mapping it, how are you indexing documents, when are you performing the count, etc.

Comment: Please see the rest code i have updated, how i am indexing,my c# class

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the size by calling `Size`. You are getting the default no of response documents.
Refer [this on Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/from-and-size-usage.html) on how to set the size

Comment: I tried with Size also like this :string UniqueID ='h';
var result = client.Search<MemberListDto>(s => s.Size(10000)
                   .Query(q =>
                               q.MatchPhrasePrefix((mq => mq.Field(f => f.UniqueID).Query(UniqueID)))
                       ));

            return result.Total;

Comment: Still , I am getting only 250 records.

Comment: This is not correct. `total` will be the total number of documents that match the query.

Comment: Can get total count of items by searching on all items. 

    var cntQuery = "{\"from\":0,\"size\":1,\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"query_string\":{\"default_operator\":\"AND\",\"query\":\" *:*\"}}]}}}";
    var cntResponse = LowlevelClient.Search<SearchResponse<dynamic>>(elasticIndexName, $"myindex_en", cntQuery);
    var cnt = cntResponse.Body.Total;